# Ошибка компиляции java

Tags: java, android

```
private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_share);
    shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) menuItem.getActionProvider();

    setIntent("Simple text");
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);


}
```

Не работает `private ShareActionProvider shareActionProvider;`

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                 java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: This is not supported, use
>   MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider()
>                                                                                     at
>   android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getActionProvider(MenuItemImpl.java:645)
>                                                                                     at
>   com.example.anonym.bitandpizza.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:32)
>                                                                                     at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)

`public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity` - пытался, ошибка компиляции пропала, но краш продолжается.
ps весь исходный код можно посмотреть [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35897015/share-action-button-action-bar-not-working), но решения не нашел

Еле-еле вроде заменил на

```
shareActionProvider = (ShareActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(menuItem);
```

Но ругается теперь на

```
shareActionProvider.setShareIntent(intent);
```

Пишет:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                   java.lang.NullPointerException
>                                                                                       at
>   com.example.anonym.bitandpizza.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:36)
>                                                                                       at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2490)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Помогла [официальная документация](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/ShareActionProvider.html).
Надо было xml код меню заменить на `app:actionProviderClass="android.support.v7.widget.ShareActionProvider"`